# Dropdown custom button in TinyMCE Joomla 3.5

Tags: button, plugins, joomla, tinymce, editor

After upgrade from Joomla 3.4 to 3.5 my Editor Buttons Plugin stopped working.
I was using a little trick to make a Custom Button appear as a dropdown menu. Anyway it doesn't work in  the new version.
What is the way to create a editor button plugin in Joomla 3.5+ that appears as a dropdown menu?

Answer (score 0):

Please check this post: http://archive.tinymce.com/wiki.php/TinyMCE3x:Creating_a_plugin on how to do that in newer versions of TinyMCE.

Note: Personally, I recommend using JCE Editor for Joomla websites - it has more features and it is easier to customize.